# How to sort my IQueryable hierarchically in a flat list?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have some flat list that I want to sort in a pseudo-hierarchical order. Without materialization using .ToList(), only IQueryable.

I do the following:

```
public class DictionaryElement
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentDictionaryElement")]
    public Guid? ParentDictionaryElementID { get; set; }
    public DictionaryElement ParentDictionaryElement { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DictionaryElement> DictionaryElements { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
 public IQueryable<DictionaryElement> Foo(DbContext db)
{
            IQueryable<DictionaryElement> allElementsQuery = db.DictionaryElements;
            //... allElementsQuery.OrderBy(); ?
            return allElementsQuery;
}
```

and data:

```
+----+---------------------------+
| ID | ParentDictionaryElementID |
+----+---------------------------+
|  1 | null                      |
|  2 | null                      |
|  3 | 1                         |
|  4 | null                      |
|  6 | 3                         |
|  5 | 2                         |
+----+---------------------------+
```

**I want to get IQueryable** which will receive such data:

```
+----+---------------------------+
| ID | ParentDictionaryElementID |
+----+---------------------------+
|  1 | null                      |
|  3 | 1                         |
|  6 | 3                         |
|  2 | null                      |
|  5 | 2                         |
|  4 | null                      |
+----+---------------------------+
```

The difference is that the second table is a hierarchy but in a flat, flat view, as it would have looked at normal display.
That is, the children immediately follow the parent

```
ID 1
   ID 3 (parentID 1)
      ID 6 (parentID 3)
ID 2
   ID 5 (parentID 2)
ID 4
```

Comment: in the tables IDs are presented in the form of INT for clarity

Comment: I don't think it is possible in general case because result would depend on QueryProvider and database. Sooner or later you will materialize your data. Why not materialize them first and then get predictable result on the client side?

Comment: There is a lot of data, and I want to do .Take() and .Skip() to get a limited set. But with a hierarchical structure, I see a problem

Comment: I haven't got a clue about your sort order "pseudo-hierarchical order". Why would element 6 come after element 1, but before element 2? Both 1 and 2 have an Id smaller than 6 and a null ParentDictionaryElementId

Comment: I have added a little description

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
return allElementsQuery.OrderBy(m => m).AsQueryable();
```